# Need help storing values i get from a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I would like to be able to store the data I get which is the sum from this while loop so I can add them together in the end.

```
public class Sum 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double second = 1;
        double n = 4;
        double start = 1;
        double sum1= 1.0;
    
         while(second<=n)
        {
            sum1 = start/second;   
            second++;
            System.out.println(sum1);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `sum1 += start/second;`

Comment: what would this do exactly?

Comment: Your question is not clear, whether you want to add(sum) all the values or you want to add(store) all the values to anywhere like Db?

Comment: Id like to get the sum of it every time it runs and add them all together so the end value would be 2.083333333. Im not sure how to keep the sum of when it runs every time if that makes more sense.

Comment: @Jonah T if you want to find the sum of all start/second results, you should use `sum1 += start/second` or `sum1 = sum1 + start / second`, but first you need to set `sum1 = 0` instead of `sum1 = 1.0`

Comment: ty for the help i think i get what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the value to the sum1 variable and at last, you can get the total of all the values.

```
public class Sum 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double second = 1;
        double n = 4;
        double start = 1;
        double sum1 = 0;

        while(second<=n)
        {
            sum1 += start/second;
            second++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum1);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: `sum1 += start/second` is logically the same as `sum1 = sum1 + start/second`

Comment: how would I go about adding the value to sum1 and getting the total of all the values tho. With it printing sum outside of the loop it just gives me the last value it ends up with.

Comment: Ohhh ok sorry i had a little misunderstanding, i think i got it now. Tysm for the help you saved me so much time lol.